# What is the best correlation coefficient for measuring the correlation of a curvilinear relationship?

Tags: regression, correlation

Also, what is the name of a curvilinear relationship that increases, peaks, and then decreases, and vice versa

Here is the relationship I got between my variables:

[image]

I believe R2 and R value are invalid for curvilinear relationships, so what would be the alternative? Also, for the curvilinear relationships, the R2 and R value can be found on the left side pf the graph. Why are they so high if they only valid for linear regression (values calculated by excel)?

I am aware that this is not a strong curvilinear relationship, but I still need to do this statistical analysis so...

Comment: What is the basis of your belief that $R^2$ is invalid?

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry!